# How can I pass an attribute in "data-target" inside a loop?

Tags: html, attributes, thymeleaf

This is my code inside a loop:

```html
<div th:each="photo : ${photos}" class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#portfolioModal{{$photo.id}}">
```

And here I would like to recall the data-target for each element of loop

```html
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal{{$photo.id}}"
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="portfolioModal1Label" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Also provide a little background why you need it as such.